# FindAll elements that not contain in sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a database with a *movement_id* column. I want to modify the function bellow to print only the movement_id that doesn't contain on the passed array arrayMovementId.

```
    arrayMovementId = [100,200,300]
    query = { movement_id: { $in: arrayMovementId } };
    models.movement.findAll({ where: query}).then(notSync => {
        let notSynchro = notSync.map(el => {
            return el.movement_id;
        })

        console.log(notSynchro)
        ...
```

My database column *movement_id* values:

```
1,4,50,200,500,6000...
```

Today it prints the element that contains on the table:

```
[200]
```

I wanna print the elements that dot not contain:

```
[100,300]
```

I've tried the $notIn but prints all the elements from the database table that doesn't match.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `arrayMovementId` after your query:

```
arrayMovementId = [100, 200, 300];
query = { movement_id: { $in: arrayMovementId } };

models.movement.findAll({ where: query }).then(notSync => {
    let notSynchro = arrayMovementId.filter(
        value => !notSync.map(el => el.movement_id).includes(value)
    );
    console.log(notSynchro)
    ...
```